# Create a Donation Link with PayPal Without Set Amount?

Tags: button, paypal, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a PayPal link which people can click to take them to a donation page. So far I have this working, but I'd really like to make it so that it doesn't specify an amount. I'd like them to choose anything they'd like.

I thought I could do this by not providing an "amount", but that just takes me to a page which says $0.00, and I can't change it.

Any suggestions? Here's my code so far:

```
<a class="donate" href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=BUSINESS&item_name=ITEM&item_number=Donation&currency_code=USD" target="_blank">Donate Now</a>
```

Comment: You need to use a form instead of a link. See here for an example https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html_example_donate/#fixed-contribution-amount  The amount is hard coded, so you need to change it to a SELECT type input to give them several options, eg $10, $50, $100, $1000, etc, or use a input type="text" to let them enter any amount. In the latter case, you need to check what they enter is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the variable amount=0.00 on to the end of your link.  They person donating just needs to click into the 0.00 area when they are on the PayPal page to change the amount to something other than 0.00 in order to proceed.

Comment: I'd think so too, but unfortunately that's not editable. Maybe they changed it. :/ PayPal is infuriating. Less so than other payment vendors, but they don't make it easy.

Comment: I just tested it myself and I am able to click in the box and edit the dollar amount.  Have you tried a different browser just to make sure its not an issue with that page using a particular browser?